# Multiple Json Object store in one Json Object Group by Year (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have Json Objec

```
{
  "2021": {
    "A177": { "Cost": 8828, "year": 2021 },
    "A276": { "Cost": 77538, "year": 2021 },
    "A188": { "Cost": 8082, "year": 2021 },
  },
  "2022": {
    "A2769": { "Cost": 3916, "year": 2022 },
    "A1779": { "Cost": 829, "year": 2022 },
    "A2709": { "Cost": 240, "year": 2022 },
  }
}
```

I would like to have:

```
[
  { "date": '2021', "A177": 8828, "A276": 77538, "A188": 8082},
  { "date": '2022', "A2769": 3916, "A1779": 829, "A2709": 240},
];
```

how can I do it?

I appreciate your help

Comment: You can use nested loops. The outer loop iterates over the properties of the top-level object, the inner loop iterates over the array elements in the value.

Comment: you might have a slight issue, this is not a valid JSON object, can you fix it so we might help a bit? in `2021` you have a duplicated key for `A177` maybe it's a mistake, but then you want to have a duplicated key as well for `A276`?... can you please double-check the original object and the result values? thxs

Comment: Either there are mistakes in the expected output, or the correlation is not clear. Could you please edit your question?

Comment: Hi, sorry for mistake, i edited json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through all the data's keys (which are the years) and then make an object that contains the year inside the date property along with the keys of the year's data.
Best explained with some code:

```
const data = ...;

let finalized = Object.keys(data).map(k => {
    let yearsData = {}; // this is a year's worth of data
    for(let l of Object.keys(data[k]))
        yearsData[l] = data[k][l]['Cost']; // fill in costs
    yearsData['date'] = k; // fill in the date
    return yearsData;
});

console.log(finalized);
```